# Apple Mail 6.2 - Turn OFF automatic checking for new messages

Tags: mail.app, email, imap

Well I am very disappointed with Apple Mail. Its checking for new e-mails automatically from time to time regardless the options.

- In General options I set "Check for new messages" to "Manually"
- In each e-mail account I turned off the option "Include when automatically checking for new messages"
- In each IMAP account i turned off the option "Use IDLE command when server supports it"

Mail still downloads new e-mails from time to time.

Any tips how to finally turn this OFF? Thank you

Comment: just quit the app?

Comment: I dont want to quit the app, because I need to work with e-mails from clients or to look up old informations in e-mails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the most effective way to accomplish this is in the "Mailbox" menu. Choose "Take all accounts offline" and you should be set. Let me know if it isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think by design when you open a mail box it is gonna check for new mail when you open it. ( or even when you open the app and open another mailbox not sure )

To turn checking of those accounts really off you need to uncheck "Enable this account"
[image: disable this account]

But then you won't be able to to access the disabled accounts not sure if that's what your looking for.

Maybe a better option is to move to a different email client? or at least those accounts you don't want to check? There are some clients available I personally like [sparrow](http://www.sparrowmailapp.com) but there are a lot of other clients available.